# Wordpress Single Sign On

Tags: wordpress, drupal, server, single-sign-on, mediawiki

Iam having 4 Wordpress sites, 2 MediaWiki sites and one Drupal site.
I want to create a Single centralized login system so that users can access all these sites with Single account. I want to host it. I don't want SSO like FB Login, G Login, etc. 
Is there any wordpress plugin or CMS or Script available for this?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stackoverflow!

What you want is implementing your own Identity Provider (IdP). Today the two most used standards are OAuth 2.0 and SAML.

For SAML - you can use for example [simpleSAMLphp](https://simplesamlphp.org/) project. It will allow you to have SSO with your own user repository and there are some nice plugins for common CMS systems (Drupal, Wordpress) to integrate with any SAML IdP.

If you're new in this field it may take you some time to fully understand and debug the SAML authentication, but it is commonly used, secure (if you do it right) and works.